# How does an Angular application starts up?

Tags: angular

Could any one describe Angular's startup? Some article on Google shows that the execution starts from main.ts and some article shows that the execution starts from index.html.

Comment: What do you mean by 'flow of execution'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Architecture** here is..

- One or More module. Default module is app.module.is
- In module one or more component or services
- Components - Html + component class.ts
- Service used to inject Business Logic

**Main.ts** is main Entry point of angular compiler, When we fire Command `ng serve` , the execution comes to `main.ts` file. and there angular bootstrap or loads default `app.module.ts`. Then in `app.module.ts` we bootstrap `app.component` using `bootstrap : [AppComponent]` in `@NgModule`.

**index.html**, Now comes to this part. in `app.component.ts` see selector have `app-root` and that is first component defined in body tag of index.html like this `<app-root> </app-root>` . This way every other Components and Modules are loaded in app-root in index.html. When request fires to angular app from browser after angular compiler finishes execution, first index.html response comes to client from server with all component files are downloaed to client side , and when user clicks any of the part of the page all content loaded from already downloaded content rather than to download each time, thats the nature of Single Page Application.

Answer (score 7):

In general (how the web works), an `index.html` file contains a `<script></script>` tag which contains a reference to a Javascript file. Once this file is downloaded by the browser, its contents will be parsed and executed.

One of the `<script></script>` tags points to an Angular Javascript file (built using the Angular compiler). Once this script runs, it boots up Angular. The starting point for Angular is the `main.ts` file. In the main.ts file there is a `bootstrapModule` method which points to the AppModule by default. It can be changed to something else if you desire so. In the AppModule Class, there is a `@NgModule` Decorator in which the bootstrap Component is defined. By default this is the AppComponent, but again, this can be changed. This bootstrap component will then be instantiated and created as an HTMLElement in the DOM where its selector is referenced in your `index.html` file.